# express body-parser bigInteger

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have created an api based on node/express. I am using body-parser to parse my request.

My problem is that I get in the request body a big integer :

759982437118771**23**

After parsing my integer becomes :

759982437118771**20**

How can i go around this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to to be a [bug of body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/278) which will **lose few digits for integers larger than 53 bits**

The correct binary represent of `75998243711877123` is: `100001110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011`

but the body-parser loses the tailing 2 bits `11` and your value becomes 
`100001110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

which is `75998243711877120`

Comment: @gpasse as is discussed in [the issue](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/278), the problem solving is still in progress. The idea was to support generic parser where you could user parser like [json-bigint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint). What I suggest is that, you pass the big number field in String format and parse it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the [`json-bigint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint) package:

```
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const JSONbigString = require("json-bigint")({ storeAsString: true });

app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: "10mb",
    extended: true,
    verify: (req, res, buf, encoding) => {
      if (
        req.url.search("/public/api/users") >=
        0
      ) {
        try {
          req.rawBody = JSONbigString.parse(buf.toString());
        } catch (e) {
          try {
            req.rawBody = JSON.parse(buf.toString());
          } catch (e) {
            req.rawBody = JSON.parse("{}");
          }
        }
      }
    },
  })
);

app.post(
  "/public/api/users",
  async (req, res) => {
    let data = req.rawBody;

    res.json(data);
    return;
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

send bigInt as string this is actually a problem with JSON.parse it does not support big int parsing so that is why the last bits are getting removed

Try Sending your big int as string

```
data = "75998243711877123"
```